# I want to set my emulator's location to Bergen(Norway)

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, android-studio-dolphin

I am trying to set my emulator's location to bergen(norway)

[image: setting the emulator location from settings but it's not changing from googleplex]

I tried different methods for setting this location.
I tried to set it using telnet localhost - geo fix, emulator's settings etc.
All the solutions I could find online, I tried.
I am using Android Studio Dolphin.
I have connected my google account to emulator.
I set the location then restarted the mac, restarted the emulator, nothing worked, it still shows googleplex as my current location.

I tried to download gps faker app but apparently I cant have playstore in my tablet emulator.

Can someone help me setting my locaiton to specific coordinates?

Comment: If I get you right you can set the specific location, but it gets lost when you restart an emulator, although you'd like it to be preserved, right?

Comment: @Onik yeah that too, but after I set the location to Bergen, the maps app location should be changed from googleplex to Bergen. But it's not changing. It's constantly showing googleplex as my location.